# High availability for a java yarn application

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

Can someone let me know what is the recommended way to ensure high availability for a yarn application?

For example, let say I have 3 physical nodes. The yarn java application needs 3 containers and each physical node has enough resources to hold 3 yarn containers. What is the recommended way to ensure that all the containers do not land upon the same physical node thereby becoming 'Single Point of Failure'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered in [hadoop-mailing list](http://hadoop-common.472056.n3.nabble.com/High-Availability-for-an-application-running-on-yarn-td4204779.html). Re-posting the answers here to prevent link rot

> You can use Placements
>   Constraints(https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/PlacementConstraints.html)
>   or set
>   yarn.scheduler.capacity.per-node-heartbeat.maximum-container-assignments
>   to 1 if you RM config with capacityscheduler.

Another approach -

> I think you can use the reservation system in Hadoop 2.8.x as well:
>   https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.5/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ReservationSystem.html